# В Blender, при анимации, объект вращается не по указанной ориентации

Tags: blender, rotation, orientation

Делал анимацию движения объекта с вращением, необходимо было чтоб объект вращался по собственной оси то есть по Local или Normal, вместо этого вращался объект не правильно, как сам выяснил вращается он по оси Global, это происходит с любым объектом при анимации.

Comment: Объект может: быть дочерним, иметь parent inverce или delta transform, вращение может быть углами Эйлера или кватернионами, Углы эйлера имеют порядок применения. Все это надо указать в вопросе или хотя бы сделать пару скриншотов.

Comment: Виноват, объект не дочерний, проверял на самом обычном кубе без каких либо изменений как объекта так и в настройках (сбросил ради интереса  на дефолт). Проблему можно сказать решил просто используя другой метод (использовал "путь"), хотя технически вопрос не решён.

Comment: К сожалению без конкретики на вопрос невозможно ответить. Может быть много примеров когда поворот работает не так как задумывалось. Самые очевидные это неправильный порядок осей или gimbal lock